# unable to create triple nested routes in react router with material ui tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to create triple nesting with react-router but it's not working.
Here is the expected output [image]
I want to perform but I am trying to implement this with the router so my tab should get switch according to URL passed to it.

1. When the user just write `/` in the URL it should redirect to login page **(working)**
2. When the user write `/dashboard` it should redirect to the dashboard with side list **(working)**
3. When the user click on list items such as about in drawer of the dashboard then it should render about page.
4. Now my about page contains two tabs one for general and one for account **(Everything was working until I implement this feature now the whole app has been crashed and not even showing the error)**

Here is my code in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-the-routes-in-react-router-dom-forked-whr5o?file=/src/App.js). **Note:** I have commented on my third nested route because it was crashing entire app

**App.js**

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Dashboard.js for nested routing**

```
import { Switch, Redirect, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import AppDrawerBar from "../components/AppDrawerBar";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <>
      <AppDrawerBar>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${path}/about`} component={About} />
          <Route path={`${path}/home`} component={Home} />
          <Redirect to={`${path}/home`} />
        </Switch>
      </AppDrawerBar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**About.js third nested routing to handle tab navigation after clicking on about list item**

```
import { Switch } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import TabMenu from "../components/TabMenu";

const About = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to about</h1>

{/* This doesn't work.. this code is to render tab navigation */}
      {/* <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from={`${props.path}/about`} to="about/general" />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/about/:page?"
          render={(props) => <TabMenu {...props} />}
        />
      </Switch> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default About;
```

**TabMenu.js to handle my tabs**

```
import { Paper, Tab, Tabs } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import General from "../pages/General";
import Account from "../pages/Account";

const TabMenu = (props) => {
  const { match, history } = props;
  const { params } = match;
  const { page } = params;

  const tabNameToIndex = {
    0: "about",
    1: "contact"
  };

  const indexToTabName = {
    about: 0,
    contact: 1
  };
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(indexToTabName[page]);
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    history.push(`/about/${tabNameToIndex[newValue]}`);
    setSelectedTab(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Paper elevation={2}>
        <Tabs
          value={selectedTab}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
        >
          <Tab label="General" />
          <Tab label="Profile" />
        </Tabs>
      </Paper>
      {selectedTab === 0 && <General />}
      {selectedTab === 1 && <Account />}
    </>
  );
};

export default TabMenu;
```